# How to add the result of an image postprocessing shader to the scene

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, framebuffer

i have an opengl context where i render several wireframe primitives. I want to apply some post processing effects (e.g. blur, bloom) on some (not all) of them. To achieve this, i've defined an offscreen framebuffer with an attached Texture (colorbuffer) and renderbuffer (depthbuffer). Then, I do the following:

1. bind the offscreen buffer
2. setup perspective view
3. draw the wireframe primitives which i want to blur
4. unbind the offscreen framebuffer and bind the "main" framebuffer
5. draw further primitives which should not be postprocessed
6. setup ortho view
7. setup the postprocessing shader, passing the texture of the offscreen buffer as uniform parameter
8. draw a fullscreen quad
9. display the content of the mainframebuffer

the problem is, that by rendering the texture to an offscreen buffer and using the result as texture for the 2D quad, i am loosing the depth information and the whole scene does not look realistic.

so my question is, how can i merge the depthbuffers of my to framebuffers? or what is a common way to apply blur or other fragmentshader effects to a complex 3D scene?

Answer (score 2):

To address this one specifically :

> so my question is, how can i merge the depthbuffers of my to
>   framebuffers?

There is nothing that stops you from sharing **attachments** between different FBOs if they are textures (Through `glFramebufferTexture2D`). This applies even for the depth/depth stencil buffer. afaik in GL3 it is even valid to use attachments of different sizes.

If you need the depth information in your main framebuffer (visible window) at a later stage you can use [Framebuffer Blitting](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Framebuffer_Blitting) to copy it. A blit operation is really fast.

There are many ways approach rendering order. Personal preference / flexibility / performance. I personally do as much as possible in FBOs because of the flexibility and optimize later if needed. The final color result is moved to the framebuffer through a blit as well.

I've had problems with sharing depth attachments (or attachments in general) on some linux drivers and in some cases under OS X, and ended up using blit instead of sharing depth attachments with great success as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd implement this using early depth testing. The idea is, that you first render the whole scene into the depth buffer only, i.e. no color writes. Next you do the color passes, where you disable depth writes and do depth test for equality using the very same transformation. This gives you the desired hidden surface removal. Do the color passes like you already outlined. Now by overlaying the blurred picture it should look alright (there are some pathological cases where this may break, but those could probably be fixed using some stencil buffer trickery).

BTW, you don't need to set up a projection for a full screen quad vertex shader. Just pass through the vertex positions and use the coordinates (-1,-1) (1,-1) (1,1) (-1,1) for the vertices.